# Common interface usage in ctor for some classes

Tags: c#

In my `CollectionService` class i want to be able to use either `DatabaseWatchService` or `RemoteFilesWatchService` therefore I used `IWatchService<IEntity> watchService` parameter which should be common for both. Nevertheless in `DoIt()` when i try to use either one of the class i am having following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'RemoteFilesWatchService' to
>   'IWatchService'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

How to fix that to able to use in `CollectionService` either one mentioned class or another.

This is the full code:

```
public interface IWatch
{
     void Watch();
}

public interface IWatchService<TDataEntity> where TDataEntity : IEntity
{
     INotificationFactory NotificationFactory { get; }
     ObservableCollection<TDataEntity> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
}

public interface IDatabaseWatchService<TDataEntity> : IWatchService<TDataEntity> where TDataEntity : IDatabaseEntity
{
     IDatabaseRepository<IDbManager> DatabaseRepository { get; }
}

public interface IRemoteFilesWatchService<TDataEntity> : IWatchService<TDataEntity> where TDataEntity : IFileEntity
{
     List<string> ExistingRemoteFiles { get; set; }
     List<RemoteLocation> RemoteLocations { get; set; }      
     IWinScpOperations RemoteManager { get; set; }
     IRemoteFilesRepository<IDbManager, TDataEntity> RemoteFilesRepository { get; }
}

public class RemoteFilesWatchService : IRemoteFilesWatchService<IFileEntity>, IWatch
{
     public INotificationFactory NotificationFactory { get; }
     public ObservableCollection<IFileEntity> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
     public List<string> ExistingRemoteFiles { get; set; }
     public List<RemoteLocation> RemoteLocations { get; set; }
     public IWinScpOperations RemoteManager { get; set; }
     public IRemoteFilesRepository<IDbManager, IFileEntity> RemoteFilesRepository { get; }

    public RemoteFilesWatchService(IWinScpOperations remoteOperator,
                IRemoteFilesRepository<IDbManager, IFileEntity> remoteFilesRepository,
                INotificationFactory notificationFactory)
    {
           RemoteManager = remoteOperator;
           RemoteFilesRepository = remoteFilesRepository;  //csv, xml or other repo could be injected
           NotificationFactory = notificationFactory;
    }

    public void Watch()
    {
    }
}

public class DatabaseWatchService : IDatabaseWatchService<DatabaseQuery>, IWatch
{
      public INotificationFactory NotificationFactory { get; }
      public ObservableCollection<DatabaseQuery> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
      public IDatabaseRepository<IDbManager> DatabaseRepository { get; }

      public DatabaseWatchService(IDatabaseRepository<IDbManager> databaseRepository,
            INotificationFactory notificationFactory)
      {
            DatabaseRepository = databaseRepository;
            NotificationFactory = notificationFactory;
      }

      public void Watch()
      {
      }
}

public class CollectionService
{
       private IWatchService<IEntity> _watchService;     

       public CollectionService(IWatchService<IEntity> watchService)
       {
             _watchService = watchService;
       }
}

class Run
{
       void DoIt()
       {          
            IWatchService<IEntity> fileWatcherServiceCsv = new RemoteFilesWatchService(new WinScpOperations(),
                                                                  new RemoteCsvFilesRepository(new DbManager(ConnectionDbType.MySql)),
                                                                  new NotificationFactory());

        var coll1 = new CollectionService(fileWatcherServiceCsv);
        }
}

public interface IEntity
{
}


public interface IFileEntity : IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
    bool RemoveFromSource { get; set; }
    string DestinationFolder { get; set; }
    RemoteLocation RemoteLocation { get; set; }
}

public interface IDatabaseEntity : IEntity
{
}

public class CsvFile : IFileEntity
{
    public int ColumnHeader { get; set; }
    public int ColumnsCount { get; set; }
    public string Separator { get; set; }
    public int ValuesRowStartposition { get; set; }
    public int ColumnRowPosition { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool RemoveFromSource { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFolder { get; set; }
    public RemoteLocation RemoteLocation { get; set; }
}

public class XmlFile : IFileEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool RemoveFromSource { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFolder { get; set; }
    public RemoteLocation RemoteLocation { get; set; }
    public string SubNode { get; set; }
    public string MainNode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just because two types, `T1`, and `T2` exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that does *not* mean that a generic parameterized by those types (`G<T1>` and `G<T2>`) exhibits the *same* relationship. An `IWatchService<IFileEntity>` is not an `IWatchService<IEntity>`. You *may* be able to do something with co/contravariance here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How could i change it to make it work? Could you post solution as an answer please.

Comment: You can't with this design The obvious fix would be `public interface IWatchService<out TDataEntity> where ...` but that's not compatible with the `ObservableCollection` that this interface exposes.

Comment: hmm, do not belive a bit that's not possible. I will be having many watchers (not only DatabaseWatchService and RemoteFilesWatchService) i need to have possibility to use them in CollectionService also in the way to allow testing therefore the parameter is as interface to allow DI.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having `IWatchService` expose a *concrete type*, I'd suggest instead having it require reimplementation of those interfaces from `ObservableCollection` that you actually want the consumers to use (or move those onto another interface and have that be what `MatchingEntries` returns).

Here I've guessed that the consumers want the events that the observable collection raises and to be able to enumerate the collection and that's all, which means we can a) implement those interfaces and b) make the interface [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance):

```
  public interface IWatchService<out TDataEntity> :
    INotifyCollectionChanged,
    INotifyPropertyChanged,
    IEnumerable<TDataEntity>
    where TDataEntity : IEntity
  {
    INotificationFactory NotificationFactory { get; }
  }
```

Now, if the implementations *choose* to use an `ObservableCollection` and just use simple wrappers to implement those interfaces or choose to *satisfy the interface in some other way* has been move back into an *implementation* decision.

Comment: MatchingEntries will be used with Add(), Count() etc.

Comment: Then the only other way I see to go is to make `DoIt` generic too.

Comment: I would like to understand: Is it because IWatchService<TDataEntity> has this generic <TDataEntity> and without it would work? P.S Is there possibility to talk in chat shortly with you?

Comment: If we can't mark the interface as covariant in `TDataEntity` (which we cannot do if it's got methods that take `TDataEntity` parameters or it returns types that aren't themselves covariant) then we get back to what I wrote in my first comment. An `IWatchService<IFileEntity>` is not an `IWatchService<IEntity>`. It's more obvious with `List<int>` not being a `List<object>` because then you could do `Add("abc")` to it.

Comment: Let's assume i just leave IWatchService without generic parameter <TDataEntity> then in CollectionService i am able to pull either DatabaseWatchService or RemoteFilesWatchService but in fact they still implement not directly IWatcherService but their own: IFileWatcherService and IDatabaseService. Why in this case this works? I would say this shoudn't work because same situation as with IEntity -> IFileEnity | IDatabaseEntity. Now it's IWatcherService -> IRemoteFileWatcher | IDatabaseWatchService. Nevertheless as mentioned it works... which i do not get.